# How to validate email and passwords like I did with first name and last name?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

Here is the codepen link: https://codepen.io/Filizof/pen/qMLbKg
HTML: Just a normal form with fields

```
<div id="maindiv">
  <h2 id="signup">Free enrollments end in <img id="myimg" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/69/69637.svg"> days!</h2>
<form id="myform">
<label class="labels" for="fname">Firstname</label><br/><input class="inputs" type="text" id="fname"><img id="check1" class="imgs" src=""><br/><br/>
<label class="labels" for="lname">Surname</label><br/><input class="inputs" type="text" id="lname"><img id="check2" class="imgs" src=""><br/><br/>
<label class="labels" for="email">Email</label><br/><input class="inputs" type="text" id="email"><img id="check3" class="imgs" src=""><br/><br/>
<label class="labels" for="pword">Create password</label><br/><input class="inputs" type="password" id="pword"><img id="check4" class="imgs" src=""><br/><br/>
<label class="labels" for="pword2">Confirm password</label><br/><input class="inputs" type="password" id="pword2"><img id="check5" class="imgs" src=""><br/><br/>
<button id="mybtn">Enroll</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript. As you can see I want it to give live feedback by showing either an X or a tick depending whether the inputs meet the requirements to be validates. I must admit the email part is a bit of a mess, but I don't understand why the passwords don't do what I want them to, which is to show a cross when it's empty, a "-" when something is typed in but not long enough and a tick when it's long enough, same for second one except when it's long enough it'll still show a minus when it's long enough unless it's the same password, that's all I want it to do, but it's not doing that.

```
document.getElementById("fname").addEventListener("keyup", validateName);
function validateName() {
var name = document.getElementById("fname");
var check = document.getElementById("check1");
if (name.value !== "") {
check.style.display = "block";
check.src = "http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_306611.png";
} else {
if (name.value == "") {
check.src = "https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/image-x-png-4.png";
}
}
}
document.getElementById("lname").addEventListener("keyup", validateSurname);
function validateSurname() {
var last = document.getElementById("lname");
var check1 = document.getElementById("check2");
if (last.value !== "") {
check1.style.display = "block";
check1.src = "http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_306611.png";
} else {
if (last.value == "") {
check1.src = "https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/image-x-png-4.png";
}
}
}
document.getElementById("email").addEventListener("keyup", validateEmail);
function validateEmail() {
var mail = document.getElementById("email");
var check2 = document.getElementById("check3");
if (mail.includes("@") == false) {
check2.style.display = "block";
check2.src = "http://pngimg.com/uploads/minus/minus_PNG56.png";
} else {
if (mail.includes("@") == true) {
check2.src = "http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_306611.png";
} else {
if (mail == "") {
check2.src = "https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/image-x-png-4.png";
}
}
}
}
document.getElementById("pword").addEventListener("keyup", 
validatePassword);
function validatePassword() {
var pass = document.getElementById("pword");
var check3 = document.getElementById("check4");
if (pass.value == "") {
check3.style.display = "block";
check3.src = "https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/image-x-png-4.png";
} else {
if (pass.length < 8) {
check3.src = "http://pngimg.com/uploads/minus/minus_PNG55.png";
} else {
if (pass.length >= 8) {
check3.src = "http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_306611.png";
}
}
}
}
document.getElementById("pword2").addEventListener("keyup", 
confirmPassword);
function confirmPassword() {
var pass2 = document.getElementById("pword2");
var pass0 = document.getElementById("pword");
var check4 = document.getElementById("check5");
if (pass2.value == "") {
check4.style.display = "block";
check4.src = "https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/image-x-png-4.png";
} else {
if (pass2.length < 8) {
check4.src = "http://pngimg.com/uploads/minus/minus_PNG55.png";
} else {
if (pass2.value != pass0.value) {
check.src = "http://pngimg.com/uploads/minus/minus_PNG55.png";
} else {
if (pass2.length >= 8 && pass2.value == pass.value) {
check4.src = "http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_306611.png";
}
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function `confirmPassword` You use `pass2` and `pass0`. Except on the last `if` where you use `pass2` and `pass`. So you will never get the tick image.

Comment: Fixed it and it still doesn't work: https://codepen.io/Filizof/pen/qMLbKg

Answer (score 0):

So for your email validations and stuff, you would need to use `mail.value.includes...` rather than just `mail.includes` as mail by itself is just an Element object and not a string and hence will not contain the `.includes()` method. This is similar to your other issues as well.

Another issue I found was there was a bit of issue with your logic. For example in the email, you had `if (mail.includes("@") == false)`...`else {if (mail.includes("@") == true)`. One of these will always return true and then you can never check `else if(mail == "")` as one of your other conditions have run. To fix that, you have to remove the `else` from the 2nd condition which ensures the `if(mail.value == '')` will run.

Also with your password validation. It is really confusing. I would suggest the best way is check whether it matches with the first password by doing a simple `if(pass2.value !== pass0.value){...} else {...}`. This makes it much more easy to read and to run. Adding onto that, a lot of your conditions aren't necessary. For example, doing `if(last.value !== ""){...}else {if(last.value == ""){...}` isn't necessary as if the first condition doesn't return true, you can just use an else and then you don't need to check for `if(last.value == "")` as you that will run. This makes the code a lot more easier to read and maintain.

I have also tested it in codepen below and inserted a snippet below (Please note I inserted some css just to make it look a bit better in the snippet):

```js
document.getElementById("fname").addEventListener("keyup", validateName);

function validateName() {
 var name = document.getElementById("fname");
 var check = document.getElementById("check1");
 if (name.value !== "") {
  check.style.display = "block";
  check.src = "http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_306611.png";
 } else {
  if (name.value == "") {
   check.src = "https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/image-x-png-4.png";
  }
 }
}
document.getElementById("lname").addEventListener("keyup", validateSurname);

function validateSurname() {
 var last = document.getElementById("lname");
 var check1 = document.getElementById("check2");
 if (last.value !== "") {
  check1.style.display = "block";
  check1.src = "http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_306611.png";
 } else {
  if (last.value == "") {
   check1.src = "https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/image-x-png-4.png";
  }
 }
}
document.getElementById("email").addEventListener("keyup", validateEmail);

function validateEmail() {
 var mail = document.getElementById("email");
 var check2 = document.getElementById("check3");
 if (mail.value.includes("@") == false) {
  check2.style.display = "block";
  check2.src = "http://pngimg.com/uploads/minus/minus_PNG56.png";
 } else {
   check2.src = "http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_306611.png";
  }
   if ( (mail.value == "" || mail.value.length == 0 || mail.value == null)) {
    check2.src = "https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/image-x-png-4.png";
   }
  }
document.getElementById("pword").addEventListener("keyup",
 validatePassword);

function validatePassword() {
 var pass = document.getElementById("pword");
 var check3 = document.getElementById("check4");
 if (pass.value == "") {
  check3.style.display = "block";
  check3.src = "https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/image-x-png-4.png";
 } else {
  if (pass.value.length < 8) {
   check3.src = "http://pngimg.com/uploads/minus/minus_PNG55.png";
  } else {
   if (pass.value.length >= 8) {
    check3.src = "http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_306611.png";
   }
  }
 }
}
document.getElementById("pword2").addEventListener("keyup",
 confirmPassword);

function confirmPassword() {
 var pass2 = document.getElementById("pword2");
 var pass0 = document.getElementById("pword");
 var check4 = document.getElementById("check5");
  
 if (pass2.value !== pass0.value) {
  check4.style.display = "block";
  check4.src = "https://mbtskoudsalg.com/images/image-x-png-4.png";
 } else {
  check4.style.display = "block";
  check4.src = "http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_306611.png";
 }
}
```

```css
#myform{
  font-size:14px;
}

img{
  width:2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="maindiv">
  <h2 id="signup">Free enrollments end in <img id="myimg" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/69/69637.svg"> days!</h2>
<form id="myform">
<label class="labels" for="fname">Firstname</label><br/><input class="inputs" type="text" id="fname"><img id="check1" class="imgs" src=""><br/><br/>
<label class="labels" for="lname">Surname</label><br/><input class="inputs" type="text" id="lname"><img id="check2" class="imgs" src=""><br/><br/>
<label class="labels" for="email">Email</label><br/><input class="inputs" type="text" id="email"><img id="check3" class="imgs" src=""><br/><br/>
<label class="labels" for="pword">Create password</label><br/><input class="inputs" type="password" id="pword"><img id="check4" class="imgs" src=""><br/><br/>
<label class="labels" for="pword2">Confirm password</label><br/><input class="inputs" type="password" id="pword2"><img id="check5" class="imgs" src=""><br/><br/>
<button id="mybtn">Enroll</button>
</form>
</div>
```